# Number of ways to write $n$ as a sum of $k$ integers (restricted digits)

Tags: combinatorics

Example:
How many ways can we write $9$ as a sum of  $4$ integers (using only single-digit integers $\in [-9, 9]$)?

> Mentioned problem's answer is the number of ways that we can generate BCD self-complementing codings.

Comment: What is the source of the problem and what have you tried?

Comment: @user This question is asked from me by my teacher as "How many self-complementing BCD codings we have?" which is equal with the example that I have mentioned. I found the answer for $\in [0, 9]$ but the negative integers made the problem harder.

Comment: Have you tried to map the problem onto the set of non-negative numbers? Do you know how to solve the latter problem?

Comment: @user: Yeah I found some solutions and also there are some answers for that problem in math.stackexchange but I don't think that may help to solve the current one because the pattern changes completely!

Comment: Please add to your question a description of your attempts and indicate where did you stuck.

Comment: @user I'll try to update the question. Thanks...